# Bending of rod due to climbing

Tags: classical-mechanics

Suppose a squirrel is climbing a rod very slowly and the rod bends an angle theta from the verticle axis. I wanted to ask why does the rod bends the torque given by the weight of the squirrel is zero at the starting as the radius vector and mg vector will be collinear thus cross product will be zero. So why does the climbing of squirrel  bends the rod and stores torsional energy it or I mean how it happens?

Answer (score 1):

The center of mass of the squirrel is not in the same line of the rod, it is separated some distance, let us say approximately half its horizontal tickness, that does produce a torque.